# Passing items into array and keeping format?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a drilldown chart like this one http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/ and I am pretty close but I am trying loop my output of my items into an array and get the same format as the demo drilldown chart however it seems to only be getting the last set of items in my each loop. How can I keep the same format and pass them into my array? https://jsfiddle.net/pwbz0mxy/

```
chart_user_hours = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'hours_chart_container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total Hours'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.2f}'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [],
        drilldown: {
            series: []
        }
    };

data = '{"comparison":false,"title":"User Capacity Breakdown | January 2016 to July 2016","series":{"name":"User Hours Breakdown ","colorByPoint":true,"data":{"series":{"data":[{"name":"test","y":10,"drilldown":"test"},{"name":"test","y":154,"drilldown":"test"},{"name":"Large Move","y":29,"drilldown":"Large Move"},{"name":"Invoice 78554","y":20,"drilldown":"Invoice 78554"},{"name":"Small Move*","y":13,"drilldown":"Small Move*"}]}}},"drilldown":{"drilldown":{"series":[{"name":"test","id":"test","work_date":["2016-06-10"],"data":[10]},{"name":"test","id":"test","work_date":["2016-07-11","2016-07-10","2016-07-08","2016-07-06"],"data":[37,51,44,22]},{"name":"Large Move","id":"Large Move","work_date":["2016-07-04","2016-07-05","2016-07-08","2016-07-11"],"data":[9,8,7,5]},{"name":"Invoice 78554","id":"Invoice 78554","work_date":["2016-06-14","2016-06-24"],"data":[10,10]},{"name":"Small Move*","id":"Small Move*","work_date":["2016-06-30","2016-06-03"],"data":[3,9]}]}}}';

var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

            chart_data = typeof obj.series.data.series != 'undefined' ? obj.series.data.series.data : '';

            chart_user_hours['series'] = [{
                name: obj.series.name,
                data: chart_data
            }];

            $.each(obj.drilldown.drilldown.series, function( key, value ) {
                chart_user_hours['drilldown']['series'] = [{
                    name: value.work_date,
                    id: value.id,
                    data: value.data
                }];
            });

                        var chart_hours = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_user_hours);
```

Comment: looks like you are doing an fresh array assign every time instead of push inside $.each

Comment: How do I go about doing a push into the array? If  you notice in the demo the for may is {name:'', id:'', data:''}, {name:'', id:'', data:''}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing the value of `chart_user_hours['drilldown']['series']` each time in your loop. So actually it has to look like this:

**Declaring the array – Before Loop**

```
chart_user_hours['drilldown']['series'] = [];
```

**Use `push` function of the array to add the value at the end of your array – In Loop**

```
chart_user_hours['drilldown']['series'].push({
       name: value.work_date,
       id: value.id,
       data: value.data
});
```